# How do I automatically generate "related articles" for my newspaper site?

Tags: html, css

Can I do it just using html and css? How do I do this with "most viewed articles"?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?  Are you trying to find collections of articles with similar content?  Are you trying to generte a list of thte most viewed articles of the day/week/month?

Comment: it doesn't matter anything related would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with just HTML and CSS. You'll need something on the server side to tell you how these articles relate.  I would suspect that you could do it with Javascript, but I can only imagine at that solution.  If you do it on the server side, then it depends on which language you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

You will need more than HTML and CSS if you need to do this automatically. You will also need to learn how to use a web programming language or environment such as PHP, ASP.NET, Ruby on Rails, Django, etc. In addition to learning a web programming language, you will also need to learn SQL which is a language needed to communicate with a database such as MySQL.